# javascript knockout data-bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Hi i have got a bog standard value in here which holds how many products are in the chosen categories.. for some reason it is not letting me data-bind the length of

```
Categories().Products
```

The length = 3 and i can see it in Google chrome watch list?

```
<!-- ko if: Categories().Products.length > 0 -->
    <span class="Basket right">
      <p data-bind:"value: Categories().Products.length"</p>
<!--/ko-->
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'Categories().Products' observableArray? If so you should use 'Categories().Products()'

```
<!-- ko if: Categories().Products().length > 0 -->
    <span class="Basket right">
       <p data-bind:"value: Categories().Products().length"</p>
    </span>
<!--/ko-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had a typo or not, but you need a colon after `ko if`

```
<!-- ko if: Categories().Products.length > 0 -->
    <span class="Basket right">
      <p data-bind:"value: Categories().Products.length"</p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And, like @ilya said, you might need to make Products an observable array too.